# Python tkinter scrollbar/graph scale slowing down scrolling

Tags: python, tkinter

I have been toying around with putting a scrollbar on my data graph.  I have it on there and its scrolling the data but its also scrolling the scale(data values) on the right hand side of the screen.  I've have toyed around this morning with the idea of creating two separate windows, one for the data graph and one for the scale.  It looks rather unusual compared to what you normally see but I do notice one thing in particular when I do this.  With the scale on the data graph, one gui, the scrolling is very slow as long as the scale still remains on the screen.  Once the scale moves off the screen the scrolling speed picks up to what I would normally expect.  When I move the scale to a completely separate gui the scrolling speed is consistently fine all the time.  How do I overcome this problem?

I'm not sure why the scale is having any kind of effect on the scrolling speed.  It's nothing more than:

```
self.DrawArea.create_line((1298, 12), (1300, 12), fill = "white")
self.DrawArea.create_line((1290, 25), (1300, 25), fill = "white")
self.DrawArea.create_line((1298, 37), (1300, 37), fill = "white")
self.DrawArea.create_text((1320, 25), text = "5.0", fill = 'white')
self.DrawArea.create_text((1320, 50), text = "4.5", fill = 'white')
self.DrawArea.create_text((1320, 75), text = "4.0", fill = 'white')
```

going down the screen(yes 5 to -5 marked out every every .125...labelled once every .5).

It is feasible to have the scale and the graph data on the same gui and still keep the scrolling speed.  I haven't changed the font, either size or type as I'm not sure how to since nothing is really indicated in the tkinter documentation.

Also is there a way that I can limit where the graph data gets displayed.  With one gui, I have the graph setup for 1350x615(600 with the bottom 15 being the scrollbar).  1300 should be the display data with the other 50 being the scale.  Right now I have the issue that the data gets graphed underneath the scale(scale is obviously put on last).  Is there any way I can limit it so the data only gets shown 0-1300 while the scale gets display 1301-1350?  I've been toying around with Frames as well this morning but I have had no luck thus far at resolving this issue.

Edited:
When I was trying to use the keyboard for scrolling I was using the .move() command but when I went to change to using the scrollbar I wasn't using the keyboard at all and just using the scrollbar.  When I have both the graph and scale on the same gui as long as the scale is on the screen(hasn't been scrolled off yet) the graph moves very slowly across the screen.  Once it's off the screen the pace picks up and moves as though I didn't have the scale on the screen at all.  It's the same way when I test with two separate windows.  The scale on the main graph slows the scrolling down.

Moving the scale to another gui still doesn't help the load speed or the zoom in/out speed for displaying the graph though.

Comment: When you say "Moving the scale to another gui" doesn't make sense. What is a "gui" in this context? An instance of `Toplevel`?

Comment: What I did was: root = Tk(), root2 = Tk().  That's what I mean by another gui.  I'm fairly new to this so my lingo isn't the best:)

Comment: you can't have two instances of `Tk` in a single program -- that will cause all sorts of unexpected problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to scroll with the scrollbar and not have the scale scroll, you should probably use two separate windows. I'm not sure what you mean by "unusual compared to what you normally see". If you put the two canvases side-by-side with no space between them and with the same background color, the user would have no way of knowing you're using two canvas widgets at the same time.

The tkinter canvas can scroll several thousand items before it starts to get sluggish, so it's hard to say without seeing your actual code.

here's an example that plots 10,000 points, with the scale in a separate canvas:

```
import Tkinter as tk
from random import randrange

class Example(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)

        self.DrawArea = tk.Canvas(self, width=1000, height=600, background="black",
                                  borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0)
        self.scale = tk.Canvas(self, width=30, height=600, background="black",
                               borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0)
        self.hsb = tk.Scrollbar(self, orient="horizontal", command=self.DrawArea.xview)
        self.vsb = tk.Scrollbar(self, orient="vertical", command=self.DrawArea.yview)
        self.DrawArea.configure(yscrollcommand=self.vsb.set, xscrollcommand=self.hsb.set)

        self.DrawArea.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.scale.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="nsew")
        self.vsb.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky="ns")
        self.hsb.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2,sticky="ew")
        self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.draw_scale()
        self.draw_points()

    def draw_scale(self):
        value = 5.0
        for y in range(25, 600, 25):
            self.scale.create_text((25, y), text=str(value), fill="white", anchor="ne")
            value -= 0.5

    def draw_points(self):
        import math
        for x in range(5,10000):
            y = randrange(600)
            color = "green" if (300 > y > 200) else "red"
            self.DrawArea.create_rectangle(x-2,y-2,x+2,y+2, fill=color)
        self.DrawArea.configure(scrollregion = self.DrawArea.bbox("all"))

root = tk.Tk()
Example(root).pack(fill="both", expand=True)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I updated the original post to add some extra detail.

Comment: Thanks for the update.  I'll give it a try when I get home after while.  I won't be able to post until tomorrow but I do see what you are referring to by the .grid.  I still haven't played enough yet with the different features of Tkinter but I have seen .grid enough.  Strangely enough in earlier renditions of the program I had been using 2 Tk instances and it never gave me any trouble.  I only stopped using it to try to shorten the code(was creating same layout twice in two instances, this idea may work much better) and I wanted to expand the main Tk height so I lost the 2nd Tk instance.

Comment: Thanks, it worked great other than one small problem I found.  I'm not sure if it's a Frame hiccup or what.  Very weird.  I'll deal with it in a completely separate question since I not so sure it might not be a problem with Frame.  I've never had the problem without the Frame statements in a program but I have the problem now.  <html>http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20957625/python-tkinter-first-line-not-drawing-in-correct-y-location</html>