# Python tkinter first line not drawing in correct y location

Tags: python, tkinter

In [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20938546/python-tkinter-scrollbar-graph-scale-slowing-down-scrolling) Brian Oakley provide some code that 99% solved an issue I was having.  When I went to run the code everything was running much better with one small exception.  The graph wasn't in the correct y location.  Anything I was trying wasn't working.  I was stumped.  Finally this morning I stumbled into the answer to the problem and I'm not sure if this is a problem, quite possibly with Frame, or what the deal is.  I'm wandering if their is another solution to the problem other than first putting a dummy point on the screen.

In the code below, if you remove the # in the first line of the `def graph_data(self):` everything works fine.  When you have the # in and don't plot a dummy point on the screen initially the lines won't show up in the correct location on the screen, y wise.  Is their another way of dealing with this as it seems to always be happening.  I am running this on linux so that might even be part of the problem...who knows.  Strangely enough when in my program I have the scale print first it always gets placed correctly but when I go to graph the data the horizontal line running across the screen never prints in the correct location unless I add a dummy point first.

```
import tkinter as tk

class Example(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)

        self.DrawArea = tk.Canvas(self, width=1300, height=600, background="black",
                                  borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0)
        self.scale = tk.Canvas(self, width=30, height=600, background="black",
                               borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0)
        self.hsb = tk.Scrollbar(self, orient="horizontal", command=self.DrawArea.xview)
        self.vsb = tk.Scrollbar(self, orient="vertical", command=self.DrawArea.yview)
        self.DrawArea.configure(yscrollcommand=self.vsb.set, xscrollcommand=self.hsb.set)

        self.DrawArea.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.scale.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="nsew")
        self.vsb.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky="ns")
        self.hsb.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2,sticky="ew")
        self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.graph_data()

    def graph_data(self):
        #self.DrawArea.create_line((0,0), (0,0), fill = "black")
        self.DrawArea.create_line((0,250), (1000,250), fill = "white")
        self.DrawArea.create_line((0,300), (2000,300), fill = "white")
        self.DrawArea.configure(scrollregion = self.DrawArea.bbox("all"))

root = tk.Tk()
Example(root).pack(fill="both", expand=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is because of this statement:

```
self.DrawArea.configure(scrollregion=self.DrawArea.bbox("all"))
```

The scrollregion defined what part of the larger virtual canvas is visible, or can be made visible by scrolling it into view. It gives the bounds of a rectangle that doesn't necessarily have to be rooted at 0,0.

The above line of code will get the bounding box ("bbox") of all of the items on the canvas. The bounding box starts with the upper-left-most item, which, in your case is at 0,250. When you create the "dummy point", the bounding box starts at 0,0*.

You can see this by adding the following line right after setting the scrollregion:

```
print("the scrollregion is", self.DrawArea.cget("scrollregion"))
```

* You might notice that the scrollregion is off by a pixel or two. On my machine it shows it as -2 248 2002 302. This is because the `bbox` method isn't 100% precise. It will sometimes fudge a little for the sake of performance. The official documentation simply states:

> The return value may overestimate the actual bounding box by a few
>   pixels.

If you know your points will always be in range of 0,0 to, say, 3000,3000, you can directly set the scrollregion to that value. Using the result of bbox is just a handy shortcut to mean "everything currently on the canvas".

In your case, you can change that configure statement to look like this:

```
self.DrawArea.configure(scrollregion=(0,0,3000,3000))
```